# Text doesn't show up in zoomed section

Tags: modifiers, video-sequence-editor

I've made a zoomed still frame in my sequence, but I want to display text at the exact same relative position as in the unzoomed sequence. This isn't working. At first I thought that I must change the position of the text strip accordingly, because it uses the unzoomed, absolute positions. But when I changed it to 0.5 0.5, where it definetly should have showed up, I couldn't see it. I tried adding the text strip to the zoom transform, not the original video strip, but that didn't help. Maybe it's important in which order I added my effects and which is attached to which? I use both a speed strip as well as a transform strip at once. Is there a certain order of adding strips on top of each other I have to keep in mind?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok so seems blender's interface is a bit unintuitive for newcommers, because after I put the text strips to the top, the main strips at the bottom and the effect strips in the middle, everything worked perfectly and as expected.

You really have to keep in mind the order (top to bottom) of your strips since they determine the layering of your, I guess, masks? It is also important which effects are applied to which strip, because similarly my speed effect (speed to zero for a freeze frame) didn't work with my transform if I applied both to the main sequence.

So top to bottom order and effect attribution are pitfalls as far as I can tell.